# I am not able to get the User.Identity.Name after redirected from controller in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

In the 1st example:-

i am assigning `User.Identity.Name` value to the variable id. i am able to get the value after that i am `Redirecting` to some other view here i am using `Redirect(ReturnUrl)` now i am able to get the `User.Identity.Name` value in the other `controller`(`Redirected` view) also

But in the 2nd example :-

i am assigning `User.Identity.Name` value to the variable id i am able to get the value after that i am `Redirecting` to some other view here i am using  `return Redirect(ReturnUrl);`when i am using `return Redirect(ReturnUrl);`am not able to get the `User.Identity.Name` value in the `Redirected` url

Example 1:-

```
public ActionResult SignIn(string ReturnUrl)
{
    if (ReturnUrl == "/" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
    {
        ReturnUrl = "/Dashboard";
    }
    var id=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    Response.Redirect(ReturnUrl);
    return View();
}
```

Example 2:-

```
public ActionResult SignIn(string ReturnUrl)
 {
    if (ReturnUrl == "/" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
    {
        ReturnUrl = "/Dashboard";
    }
    var id=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
 }
```

My Controller:- In this function if i am `return Redirect(ReturnUrl);` i am not able to get the `User.Identity.Name` value in CompanyRequired filter if i am using `Response.Redirect(ReturnUrl); return View();` then able to get the `User.Identity.Name` value in `CompanyRequired filter` but i have to use `return Redirect(ReturnUrl);`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignInCallback()
    {
        var token = Request.Form["id_token"];
        var state = Request.Form["state"];
        var claims = await ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(token, state);
        string ReturnUrl = state.Substring(state.IndexOf('?') + 1); 
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies");
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);
        if (ReturnUrl == "/" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
        {
            ReturnUrl = "/Dashboard";
        }
        var Id = User.Identity.Name; 
        return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
    }
```

View:-  Here i control will go to the CompanyRequired filter there i need a User.Identity.Name value in that i am getting value null

```
[Authorize,CompanyRequired]
public class DashBoardController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

CompanyRequired Filter:-

```
 public class CompanyRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext     filterContext)
    {
        var coCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CoId"];

        if (coCookie == null)
        {
        var Id= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Int(); **//here i need to get the value but i am getting null value**
        IdNmList cos = new EmployeeDAL().GetCompany(Id);
            if (cos.Count == 0)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "controller" , "Company"},
                    { "action" , "Add"}
                });
            }
            else if (cos.Count == 1)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CoId", cos[0].Id.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                 {
                            { "controller", "Company" },
                            { "action", "Select" },
                            { "ReturnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
                 });
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }       
}
```

Comment: In your controller you shouldn't need to use `HttpContext.Current`, `User` should already be accessible.

Comment: ya without `HttpContext.Current`, we can access the value. after rediraction i am not able to get if i am using ` return Redirect(ReturnUrl);`

Comment: We need more information about how you are using `SignIn` I think, as it stands it should make literally no difference as you're calling `User.Identity.Name` before your redirect.

Comment: after login. i will Redirected to dashboard for this controller i am having filter in that filter not able to access the `User.Identity.Name` value.

Comment: You understand that once you leave the scope of `SignIn`, your `id` variable is destroyed?

Comment: scope of the id will be destroyed after the method end yes but my question is that i am no able to get the value in `User.Identity.Value` in other controller.

Comment: You mean in the `Dashboard` action?

Comment: I have just tried your code and it actually works both ways for me. Your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: i have update post u can check once..

Comment: for this application i am using `OwinStartup class` whether Problem with this class because while searching i saw some where , if we are having `OwinStartup` class then null value will occur in the `User.Identity.Name`.